# Non-uniqueness of the k-vector in Bloch state

Tags: quantum-mechanics, solid-state-physics, crystals

How to understand that Bloch wave solutions can be completely characterized 
by their behaviour in a single Brillouin zone? Given Bloch wave:
\begin{equation*}
\psi_{\mathbf{k}}(\mathbf{r}) = u_{\mathbf{k}}(\mathbf{r}) \exp (i\mathbf{k}\mathbf{r})
\end{equation*}
I can write wavefunction for momentum $\mathbf{k}' = \mathbf{k} + \mathbf{G}$.
\begin{equation*}
\psi_{\mathbf{k}+\mathbf{G}}(\mathbf{r}) = u_{\mathbf{k}'}(\mathbf{r})\exp(i\mathbf{G}\mathbf{r})\exp (i\mathbf{k}\mathbf{r})
\end{equation*}
As I understand $u_{\mathbf{k}'}(\mathbf{r})\exp(i\mathbf{G}\mathbf{r}) \neq u_{\mathbf{k}}(\mathbf{r})$, so:
\begin{equation*}
  \psi_{\mathbf{k}+\mathbf{G}}(\mathbf{r}) \neq \psi_{\mathbf{k}}(\mathbf{r}).
\end{equation*}
Or I am wrong?

P.S. 
If Bloch functions are periodic in $\mathbf{k}$ space, then why free particle solution is not a Bloch function ($V=0=V(\mathbf{r}) = V(\mathbf{r} + \mathbf{G})$).

Comment: Why do you think free particle wavefunctions are not Bloch functions? They are, and in the first Brillouin zone their periodic part (which you denote by $u_k$) is constant.

Comment: However $\exp(ikr) \neq \exp(i[k + G]r)$ and energy is parabolic $\neq$ periodic.

Comment: I made a wikipedia image on this topic: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:BlochWaves1D.svg See the caption too. Does that help? If not, what's confusing about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's consider the simplest problem: electron in free space. As free space is completely periodic, we can take an arbitrary value $a$ as a period of the potential. That is
$$V(x)=\textrm{const.}=V(x+a),$$
which allows the application of Blochs theorem.
Now Schrödinger's equation for such electron looks (in dimensionless units) like

$$-\psi''(x)=K^2\psi(x),\tag1$$

where $K$ is (vacuum) wavenumber of the electron, $K^2=E$ is total energy. Using Bloch's theorem, we can substitute $\psi(x)=u(x)e^{ikx}$:

$$-u''(x)-2iku'(x)+k^2u(x)=K^2u(x).\tag2$$

Here $k$ is quasiwavenumber. General solution of $(2)$ is

$$u(x)=A\exp(-i(k+K)x)+B\exp(-i(k-K)x).\tag3$$

By Bloch's theorem we know that $u(x)=u(x+a)$, the same goes for its derivative. Thus, we can impose periodic boundary conditions on $(2)$ and find the particular solution. From $u(0)=u(a)$ we can get using $(3)$:

$$A=B\left(\frac{e^{2iaK}-1}{e^{ia(k+K)}-1}-1\right),\tag4$$
thus

$$\frac{u(x)}B=e^{-i(k-K)x}+e^{-i(k+K)x}\left(\frac{e^{2iaK}-1}{e^{ia(k+K)}-1}-1\right).\tag5$$

$B$ is normalization constant, for our purposes we can ignore it, taking $B=1$.

Now, from $u'(0)=u'(a)$ we have restriction on $K$:

$$K=k-\frac{2\pi n}a,\,n\in\mathbb{Z}.\tag6$$

Substituting $(6)$ into $(5)$, we get:

$$u(x)=\exp\left(-i\frac{2\pi n}ax\right).$$

Finally, we get our Bloch solution for free electron:

$$\psi(x)=\exp\left(-i\frac{2\pi n}ax\right)\exp(ikx)=\exp\left(i\left(k-\frac{2\pi n}a\right)x\right).$$

You may see that this function is parametrized by two values: $k\in\mathbb{R}$ and $n\in\mathbb{Z}$. $k$ is quasiwavenumber, while $n$ indexes branches of $E(k)$ dependence.

For each $k$ we have a set of possible energies, each corresponding to some band. These bands are uniquely (for given $k$) determined by $n$. Now what happens if you replace $k\to k-G=k-\frac{2\pi}a$? Simple:

$$K_n=k-\frac{2\pi n}a\;\to\; \left(k-\frac{2\pi}a\right)-\frac{2\pi n}a,$$

and right hand side of the above is nothing but

$$RHS=\left(k-\frac{2\pi}a\right)-\left(\frac{2\pi (n+1)}a-\frac{2\pi}a\right)=k-\frac{2\pi(n+1)}a=K_{n+1}.$$

I.e. if you increase $k$ so far as to go out of first Brillouin zone, **you just end up in another band**. I.e. **you don't get new states** this way.

This just means that the band structure can be seen in [extended zones scheme](http://what-when-how.com/electronic-properties-of-materials/energy-bands-in-crystals-fundamentals-of-electron-theory-part-1/):

[image: free electron in extended zones scheme]

([picture source](http://what-when-how.com/electronic-properties-of-materials/energy-bands-in-crystals-fundamentals-of-electron-theory-part-1/))

If you look at the picture above, you'll see that the fact that you appeared in a different band is just an artifact of our band indexing and the form of the solution. You could as easily continuously move along the lines in the picture *periodically*. And it appears that this motion is actually more natural for crystals, due to the places where the bands split. Here's how it looks for non-free electron in crystal:

[image: band splitting in extended zones scheme]

Comment: Thank you, your explanation is very helpfull. My problem was that I never considered to solve Schrodinger equation with Bloch wave form. I thougt that $Ae^{ikx} + Be^{-ikx}$ is the solution for periodic = constant potencial. However if I undestand correctly the difference between one and many parabolas is Born-von Karman boundary conditions. I still need to contemplate on this difference, but again thank you, for me it was big jam. Now it is clear what means **to define** $u_{k+G,n}(x)\exp(iGx)=u_{k,n}(x)$ so that $\psi_k(x)$ are periodic in $k$ space.

Answer (score 3):

$u_k(r)$ has the periodicity of the crystal. Therefore, its Fourier expansion only includes reciprocal lattice vectors:

$$u_k(r)= \sum_GC_{k-G}e^{iG\cdot r}.$$
Therefore,
$$u_{k'}(r)\exp(iGr)=u_k(r).$$

Comment: Sorry, I still don't see why $\sum_{\mathbf{G}_i} C_{\mathbf{k} + \mathbf{G}, \mathbf{G}_i}
\exp(i\mathbf{G}_i\mathbf{r})
\exp(i\mathbf{G}\mathbf{r}) = \sum_{\mathbf{G}_i} C_{\mathbf{k}, \mathbf{G}_i}
\exp(i\mathbf{G}_i\mathbf{r})$

Comment: By change of variables, you can define $G->G+G'$ Since we are summing over all $G$s, both summation becomes equivalent. Reference: Ashcroft and Mermin

Comment: Actually I think that you are wrong. In [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloch_wave#Meaning_and_non-uniqueness_of_the_k-vector) it is written that for different $k$'s, $u$'s can be different (look at picture)!

Comment: Yes, $ u's$ can be different. I haven't said that $u's $ are same. I have multiplied it by a term.