# Do Bloch waves from different bands have different energies and wave functions?

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, wavefunction, crystals

What I have understood from the concept of reducing a Bloch wave $\psi_{n,k}(x)=e^{ikx}u_{n,k}(x)$ to the first Brillouin zone is the following:
$$\psi_{n,k+\frac{2 \pi}{a}m}(x)=\psi_{n-m,k}(x),\tag1$$ with $m$ and $n$ integers and lattice period $a$. I can see this easily mathematically by repeating the argument in the answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/211208/non-uniqueness-of-the-k-vector-in-bloch-state), and I also come to the same intuitive conclusion: the answer there states: "I.e. if you increase $k$ so far as to go out of first Brillouin zone, **you just end up in another band**. I.e. you don't get new states this way."

Now comes my question. It's not clear to me if and/or why in addition to $(1)$, $$\psi_{n,k+\frac{2 \pi}{a}m}(x)=\psi_{n-m,k}(x)=\psi_{n,k}(x).\tag2$$ The latter seems to be suggested by e.g. the answer to [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/550787/dissatisfied-with-textbook-explanations-for-why-vec-k-in-blochs-theorem-can?rq=1) question. I have two problems.

1. It seems contradictory to the statement above. Instead, it suggests that if you increase $k$ so far as to go out of first Brillouin zone, **you just end up in *the same* band**.
2. When I look at a band diagram, the statement $\psi_{n-m,k}(x)=\psi_{n,k}(x)$ makes no sense to me. The whole point of the diagram is I'd say, that for one $k$ value, there exist different Bloch waves $\psi_{n-m,k}(x) \neq \psi_{n,k}(x)$ with different energies, no?

Comment: This may help: https://thiscondensedlife.wordpress.com/2018/02/11/pictures-of-band-theory-a-real-space-picture-of-where-bands-and-band-gaps-come-from/

Comment: @Xcheckr It should do. Very interesting.

Answer (score 0):

We can write $$\psi_{k + \frac{2\pi}{a}}(x) = e^{i(k + \frac{2\pi}{a})x}u(x) = e^{ikx}e^{2\pi i\frac{x}{a}}u(x)$$ But $e^{2\pi i\frac{x}{a}}$ has period $a$, so the function $$u'(x) \equiv e^{2\pi i\frac{x}{a}}u(x)$$ is also periodic with period $a$. Our original wave is thus equivalent to
$$ \psi'_k(x) = e^{ikx}u'(x)$$
which is a Bloch wave at wavevector $k$.

The energies of $ \psi'_k $ and $\psi_{k + \frac{2\pi}{a}} $ are the same, since they're the same wave. The set of possible energies at $k + \frac{2\pi}{a}$ and $k$ are also the same. $n$ just describes where the energy of $\psi$ lies in the ordered list of possible energies at $k$, so $n$ must be the same for $ \psi'_k $ and $\psi_{k + \frac{2\pi}{a}} $.

Comment: "wavevector $k$" Do you mean **wavenumber**? A vector would be noted as $\vec{k}$ or $\mathbf{k}$. Sorry to sound pedantic.

Comment: Well, in this case it's a vector of dimension 1. :)

Comment: Looks like something of dimension $[k]=L^{-1}$. Does it relate to the wave number as used in wave theory and the wave equation in QM? (TISE)

Comment: That doesn’t solve it for me, sorry. This to me looks like the derivation leading to (1), not (2). Also, I am always extremely confused when the words ‘is equivalent to’ are used. (And they are, in this context, very often.) Does it mean = ? Or does it mean they have a certain parameter which is equal? If so, which parameter do these waves share that is equal?

Comment: @Gert Daniel means a one-dimensional (1D) vector

Comment: By "equivalent to" I mean $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$, we have $\psi'_k(x) = \psi_{k + \frac{2\pi}{a}}(x) $. As equal as can be. Because these two  functions describe exactly the same wave, it follows that they must have the same energy. And because the set of energy levels at $k + \frac{2\pi}{a}$ is the same as the set of energy levels at $k$, the two waves also have the same $n$.

Comment: @Gert yes, wavenumber is the 1D case of a wavevector. (Although I think "wavenumber" is sometimes used to mean $|k|$, whereas here I mean the signed version).

Comment: @Laura you're right that my original answer skipped the key step, I've tried to edit it in above.

Comment: @Daniel Yes, usually the wave number is a scalar, so $|k|$. Not limited to 1D though...